# Trying to make the player rotate perpendicular to the model's meshes. Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently working on a school game project where i need to have the player climb walls and pick up stuff. I am currently stuck in figuring out how to make the player rotate perpendicular to where the model's faces are while he/she moves towards a corner of a wall as shown below.

Something like this:[image: Example!]

I searched for some methods to achieve this but i haven't found anything concrete so far.

Edit: I tried Reasurria's method and it kinda works.

```
if (Physics.Raycast (transform.position, -transform.up, out hit) && hit.collider.GetComponent<WallModifier> ()) {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation (hit.normal, Vector3.right);
            //Physics.gravity = hit.normal * -10.0f;
        }
```

My player does indeed rotate correctly pependicular to the slope/wall but then my camera code completly breaks when trying to actually climb the wall. [This shows how it looks like in first person](https://gyazo.com/50df2ebe3c649ca594e948c4b5e02987) and [this shows how it looks like in the scene view](https://gyazo.com/5e8a5f3294a164c4572cdc158363c213).

While very funny, it is not obviously desired to have such effect.
Here is the camera code:

```
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Escape) || toggle && Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
        toggle = !toggle;
    }
    if (!toggle && Application.isFocused) {
        Cursor.visible = false;
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        var md = new Vector2 (Input.GetAxisRaw ("Mouse X"), Input.GetAxisRaw ("Mouse Y"));
        md = Vector2.Scale (md, new Vector2 (sensitivity * smoothing, sensitivity * smoothing));
        smoothV.x = Mathf.Lerp (smoothV.x, md.x, 1f / smoothing);
        smoothV.y = Mathf.Lerp (smoothV.y, md.y, 1f / smoothing);
        mouseLook += smoothV;
        mouseLook.y = Mathf.Clamp (mouseLook.y, minClamp, maxClamp);
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis (-mouseLook.y, (Vector3.right + transform.right).normalized);
        character.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis (mouseLook.x, character.transform.up.normalized);
        if (rotateModel && antModel)
            antModel.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis (-mouseLook.y, (Vector3.right + transform.right).normalized) * Quaternion.Euler (0, 90, 0);
    } else {
        Cursor.visible = true;
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
        Application.runInBackground = false;
    }

}
```

This code was taken by this [person](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=blO039OzUZc).

Comment: Do you mean perpendicular to the floor/wall?

Comment: That crazy result looks more like a physics issue than a camera issue. Maybe something to do with the camera script also changing the model rotation. You should remove my answer as accepted though as it did not solve the problem correctly :)

Comment: This also seems relevant to your issue, but it uses some NavMesh things. https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/navigation/walking-walls-and-ceilings

Comment: I have figured out the issue but i cant seem to find any way into solving it without completly rewriting the camera code.  The fault lies within this line: 


`character.transform.localRotation=Quaternion.AngleAxis(mouseLook.x, character.transform.up.normalized);` 


Think you can find another method of making that particular line work without affecting the character itself?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean perpendicular? In other words, rotate along x axis with -90 degree.

```
transform.Rotate(new Vector3(-90, 0, 0));
```

Comment: Yes, but since this is a player, i want this to happen as i move into the corner showcased in the picture above. Apparently i cant type english very well so pardon me.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you may want to use [Raycast.normal](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit-normal.html). So you would raycast from your player position with a direction equal to your player's local Vector3.down (`player.transform.up * -1.0f`).

You can use `Quaternion.LookAt(surfaceNormal)` to align your players 'up' vector with the normal of the surface under the player. This may involve some 90 degree offset to make the two 'up' vectors match.

Depending on your goal you may also want to set [Physics.gravity](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics-gravity.html) to `surfaceNormal * -10.0f` or implement some custom gravity solution if the new surface will function as ground.

Comment: I didnt even know a such things as `Quaterion.LookAt(surfaceNormal)` and Raycast.normal even existed. I will give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can add empty GameObject with attached collider, than you can use OnTriggerEnter to rotate your Player. Add flag and on every odd enter rotate in one side and on every even enter rotate to opposite side as shingo said

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vxCb.png)

Comment: Could do that, but i dislike the idea of using colliders for something that can be efficiently written in code. If the scripting side of things dont work at all, i could maybe fall back to this.

Comment: Ok, just check player's position. If it's more than some value (for example, wall.transform.position - 0.1f) you can apply your rotation)

Comment: I meant wall.transform.position - new Vector3(0.1f, 0, 0)